# How to run Karma using TeamCity reporter using QUnit

Tags: teamcity, qunit, karma-runner

I'm trying to run Karma with the TeamCity reporter.  But when I run the test suite, it fails with:

```
Error: No provider for "framework:qunit"! (Resolving: framework:qunit)
```

This works fine when the output is set to 'progress', but not when I add 'teamcity'.

My karma config looks as follows:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['qunit'],
    files: [
      'scripts/nml/marco/tests/tempTest.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    reporters: ['progress', 'teamcity'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

My test is still very simple:

```
(function () {
    test('Test one equals one', function () {
        equal(1, 1);

    });
})();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. When I installed the TeamCity reporter, I did it to my current folder instead of the global karma folder. So I think the runner got confused with only a small set of files being in the current folder (and that overrode the global settings).

I was wrong, the tests did not pass any more when just running with the 'progress' reporter.